# C# Winforms - programmatically adding to the font table doesn't affect the application until the app restarts (using addFontResource)

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic, fonts

My application has a custom font that it needs to install, MSDN has an [addFontResource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-addfontresourcea?redirectedfrom=MSDN) function that will add to the temporary font table. I've tested that this method does successfully add to the font table using the following code.

```
public static class StaticFoo
{
    [DllImport("gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "AddFontResourceW", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern int AddFontResource([In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
                                        string lpFileName);
    public static void SetFont()
    {
        AddFontResource(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Geomanist-Regular.otf"));
    }
}
//and then in my main
static void Main()
{
    StaticFoo.SetFont();
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

My problem is that even if I add the font at the start of my main method, it doesn't get used during that instance of the application. After a clean restart of my computer (and the font table), running the app once will get some random default font used, closing and then opening the app will then use the correct fonts. Evidently the check for whether or not the font exists is happening before my SetFont method completes the temp install.

Is there a way to trigger SetFont before the font check? (assuming that's why my font isn't being used) or a command to 'refresh' the Controls/Fonts to make the app doublecheck the font table?

Edit: I've now tried using a privateFontCollection, with the above code the same except for the SetFont method

```
PrivateFontCollection privateFontCollection = new PrivateFontCollection();
privateFontCollection.AddFontFile(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath), "Geomanist-Regular.otf"));
```

and still no updated fonts on the first launch of the application

Comment: Why are you using `AddFontResource`? That's for all applications. And you need to broadcast the change. You can add Fonts using the `PrivateFontCollection` class (which will also call  `RemoveFontResourceEx` for you when you dispose of it), or maybe use `AddFontResourceEx` directly (what the `PrivateFontCollection` already does for you, too)

Comment: @Jimi I've now attempted using the privateFontCollection, but I'm still having no luck

Comment: The `PrivateFontCollection` needs to be a Field and live for the life-span of the application. You dispose of it when the starting Form closes. Move it to the constructor of the Form you run first. BTW, that's an OTF, not a TTF: what are you using it for? (not relevant: `Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Geomanist-Regular.otf")`)

Comment: Awesome, ill try that when I’m back at work in a few weeks, thanks! And the otf is because our branding/UI people declared it as the company font, I’m setting up one of our main client facing apps to use said font instead of whatever the default was  (our graphics/UI girl wanted to see what it looked like)